# TypeORM migration generation failed: Emit skipped

Tags: nestjs, typeorm, ts-node, nrwl-nx

I use TypeORM with NestJS in a NX Workspace (with Apps and Libs).
It is a TypeScript project.
I am trying to generate migration.

I have created the ormconfig.json file for the typeorm CLI:

```
{
  "type": "postgres",
  "host": "localhost",
  "port": 5432,
  "username": "***",
  "password": "***",
  "database": "***",
  "synchronize": false,
  "logging": true,
  "entities": [
    "apps/api/src/app/**/*.entity.ts",
  ],
  "cli": {
    "migrationsDir": "apps/api/src/migration"
  }
}
```

To generate migration I use these commands:

```
"typeorm": "./node_modules/.bin/ts-node --project apps/api/tsconfig.app.json -r tsconfig-paths/register ./node_modules/.bin/typeorm",
"typeorm:migration:run": "yarn typeorm migration:run",
"typeorm:migration:generate": "yarn typeorm  migration:generate -n PostRefactoring",
"typeorm:migration:create": "yarn typeorm  migration:create -n PostRefactoring"
```

And I have this error:

```
TypeError: apps/api/src/app/folder1/myEntity.entity.ts: Emit skipped
    at getOutput (.../node_modules/ts-node/src/index.ts:755:17)
    at Object.compile (.../node_modules/ts-node/src/index.ts:968:32)
    at Module.m._compile (.../node_modules/ts-node/src/index.ts:1056:42)
    at Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1153:10)
    at Object.require.extensions.<computed> [as .ts] (.../node_modules/ts-node/src/index.ts:1059:12)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:977:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:877:14)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1019:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:77:18)
    at .../src/util/DirectoryExportedClassesLoader.ts:41:22
```

I am using NX Libraries so my entities import some files like:

`import { ... } from '@xxx/yyy'`

(@xxx/yyy is a lib path)

Do you have any suggestions to fix this issue ?

Thank you for your help

Comment: `npm i` solved this problem for me

Answer (score 2):

typeorm migration requires js files to run the migration. You should first convert ts files to js files. TypeScript files outside of the project folder will produce an Emit skipped error.

**tsconfig.json** - this config will convert ts file in src folder to js files in dist folder.

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs",
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "target": "es6",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "outDir": "./dist",
    "rootDir": "./src"
  }
}
```

**Edit:** You have to comment out `allowJS` field in the ormconfig file